# Cancel and start AsyncTask again in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble starting a task after it has been cancelled the first time.  It will run when entering the view, and starting the task, then cancel works when the fragment is first destroyed.  But when re-entering the view, the `AsyncTask` will no longer run.

Is it possible some class state that needs to be cleaned up?  Or do I need to remove the `Fragment` with the `AsyncTask` from the back stack?

Here is my code below:

```
package com.emijit.lighteningtalktimer;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.emijit.lighteningtalktimer.data.Timer;
import com.emijit.lighteningtalktimer.data.TimerContract.TimerEntry;


public class RunTimerFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = RunTimerFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private View rootView;
    private Uri mUri;
    private long mTimerId = 0;
    private Timer mTimer;
    private RunTimerTask mRunTimerTask;

    private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;

    public static String URI = "URI";

    public RunTimerFragment() {
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView intervals;
        TextView timerSeconds;
        TextView timerMinutes;
        TextView timerHours;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            intervals = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.run_timer_intervals);
            timerSeconds = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer_seconds);
            timerMinutes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer_minutes);
            timerHours = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer_hours);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_run_timer, container, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootView);
        rootView.setTag(viewHolder);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            mUri = arguments.getParcelable(URI);
            if (mUri != null) {
                mTimerId = ContentUris.parseId(mUri);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mTimerId: " + mTimerId);
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (mTimerId != 0) {
            return new CursorLoader(
                    getActivity(),
                    TimerEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    TimerEntry._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { Long.toString(mTimerId) },
                    null
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            mTimer = new Timer(cursor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        mRunTimerTask = new RunTimerTask();
        mRunTimerTask.execute(mTimer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mRunTimerTask.cancel(true);
    }

    private class RunTimerTask extends AsyncTask<Timer, Integer, Long> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = RunTimerTask.class.getSimpleName();

        Timer mTimer;
        int mCurrentSeconds = 0;
        int mCurrentIntervals = 0;

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Timer... params) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "doInBackground");
            mTimer = params[0];

            while (mTimer.getIntervals() > mCurrentIntervals) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    mCurrentSeconds++;
                    publishProgress(mCurrentSeconds);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
            return (long) mCurrentIntervals;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // do stuff
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
            super.onPostExecute(aLong);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be in the catch block. Not sure about the mTimer.getIntervals() because it's from third party.

When you cancel the task. The InterruptedException will be caught in the task thread. Then your loop will still keep going because you didn't return or break the loop.

Since all AsyncTask will be queued up in one thread pool of size 1, even if you start another AsyncTask, it will still be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, I cannot see any call to startTimer(). Should you be overiding onResume() and calling startTimer() in there?